# Iterate over a 2D array in Java

Tags: java

I am very new in java and I was wondering is there any way to avoid to hardcode the "4" on the second for loop? thanks

```
 public class Test {   public static void main(String[] args){
         double [][] array2D = {{1,2,3,4},{10,11,12,13},{100,101,102,103}};
         for(int i = 0 ; i < array2D.length ; i++){
           for(int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
             System.out.println(array2D[i][j]);
         } } } }
```

Comment: Use `array2d[i].length`.

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array2D));`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a jagged 2D array the answer in the comment section works

```
for (int i=0; i< array2D.length; i++) 
{ 
    for (int j=0; j< array2D[i].length; j++) 
        System.out.println(array2D[i][j]);
}
```

if you have a 2D array where the number of columns is constant

```
for (int i=0; i< array2D.length; i++) 
{ 
    for (int j=0; j< array2D[0].length; j++) 
        System.out.println(array2D[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: why would you use solution 2, when solution 1 would work for a Jagged or non-Jagged array?

Comment: ideally I would not want to perform a length operation again and again so that the solution scales. I would want to calculate the number of rows and columns even before running the loops